# Which case is used with "не раздумывая ни"?

Tags: падежи

In the expression **не раздумывая ни секунды/минуты** are the time elements accusative plural or genitive singular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of negative statement, "ни" will serve as particle and word depending on it (most likely noun, but not necessary) will be used in genitive case, singular:

> 1.*Част.* В отрицательном предложении означает полное отсутствие упоминаемого объекта, обозначаемого в родительном падеже.
>   *Я не видел там ни одного солдата.*
>   [source](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B8)

This rule will apply to the negative statements where "ни" is used.

Answer (score 1):

This is **genitive singular** (родительный падеж).

Answers the question: кого? чего? - секунды, минуты.

Similar: не терять ни секунды.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes they even say "Не раздумывая ни **единой** секунды". So it should be obvious it's singular.

Comment: Obvious if you have seen that, which I hadn't.